# Smartwatch Gear 2 gyroscope data output sampling rate

Tags: tizen, motion-detection, tizen-wearable-sdk, sensor-fusion

I am collecting data coming from accelerometer and gyrospcope sensor on my Smartwatch: Samsung Gear 2 .
The development environment is: Tizen SDK for Wearable Version 1.0.0.

The javascripts code used is:

```
window.addEventListener("devicemotion",deviceMotionEvent,true);

function deviceMotionEvent(e) {

Ax = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x / 9.8,
Ay = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y / 9.8,
Az = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z / 9.8,

Wx = e.rotationRate.alpha,
Wy = e.rotationRate.beta,
Wz = e.rotationRate.gamma;

}
```

The problem:
While acceleration data seem to be correct (sampling frequency about 25 Hz) the rotation rate along the alpha,beta,gamma axis presents an anomaly:
the sampling rate is very low (1.0 Hz). The same value of Wx,Wy,Wz is repeated 25 times given that the deviceMotionEvent is fired at 25 Hz.

I have not intercepted any document including the gyro sensor specifications (any suggestion is welcome) but I would understand if 1.0 Hz for the gyro has to be considered an anomaly or the correct functioning.

V

Comment: What is you precise question?:)

Comment: A sampling rate approximately equal to 1.0 Hz , for the gyro has to be considered an anomaly or the correct functioning? I did not found any Samsung's document including this information. From my perspective 1 Hz is totally insufficient for any motion analisys.